# inserting dataframe to mysql table efficiently

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe

I'm looking to insert a df into a mysql table, but I want to do it a lot faster than what I have right now, cause it's extremely slow. Here is my code.

```
            for i in range(len(mydf)):
            try:
                mydf.iloc[i:i+1].to_sql(save_table, con=my_engine, schema='my_schema', index=False, if_exists='append')
            except exc.IntegrityError as e:
                pass
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error("General exception was passed. Error was {}".format(e))
                pass
```

My previous way was to do it this way, but it would be an endless loop on a duplicate row if the table already has that row. Because it would start the process over using this.

```
try:
   mydf.to_sql(save_table, con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
except exc.IntegrityError as e:
   logging.info("Bypassing duplicates")
except Exception as e:
   logging.info("General exception was passed. Error was {}".format(e))
```

Wondering if I should convert my df to a list and loop through it that way or there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to be the fastest thing.

```
list_values = [tuple(r) for r in self.main_sdn.to_numpy().tolist()]
try:
   cur.executemany(query_string, list_values)
   con.commit()
except exc.IntegrityError as e: 
   pass
except Exception as e:
   con.rollback()
   logging.error("Exception was {}".format(e))
   con.close()
```